# Great Expectations fails to Import

Tags: python-3.x, great-expectations

All,

Why am I getting the error "**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'great_expectations'**" when I run "import great_expectations as gx"? I did install great_expectations library version **0.18.3** using "**pip install Great_expectations**"

Note that I'm using a Windows Laptop with Python 3.10.11

Thanks,
Gopi

Comment: Did you try pip install great-expectations or pip install Great_expectations?

Comment: Dinux - It does not matter weather  I use "pip install great_expectations" or "pip install great-expectations" it does not error out. But import cannot handle great-expectations and this includes from the command line as well. However import great_expectations as gx is erroring out with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'great_expectations'"

Answer (score 0):

I was using Visual Studio Code and for some reason it was not recognizing the package. I used pycharm and installed it using the tools package management utility and it worked